# How do I use reflection to get a property and use it in a query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, reflection

I have a generic method and I want to add a search capability to my method. as parameter I get the name of property(string) and the value(string) it should search for in the list. how can I achieve this?

**This code is not the exact code I have so it may seem that I can use other options like Expression functions which is not possible in my case cause it should be consumed in an Api Controller
**I use unit of work with repository pattern in real project and for sake of simplicity I have tryed to add it up in one simple function

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<List<T>>> GetAll(string? filterProperty = null, string? filterValue = null)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
    if (filterProperty != null)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(filterProperty);
        query = query. Where(u=> u.property.Contains(filterValue));
    }
    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `IQueryable` you'll want to create a `LambdaExpression` for the filter predicate. (For `IEnumerable` you can compile that expression into an appropriate `Func<>`.)

This all works by building an expression tree that represents the action you want to perform. In this case you're calling `Contains` on the result of getting the property value, passing a constant for the filter value.

Let's start with the `Contains` method, which you can reuse. Rather than basic reflection, here's how you can get it using an expression:

```
static readonly MethodInfo _contains =
  (((Expression<Func<string, bool>>)(s => s.Contains("a"))).Body as MethodCallExpression)
  .Method;
```

While that might look a little confusing, it's leveraging the compiler to do the reflection work for us. Sometimes it's easier than searching for the right version of a method with multiple overloads, or when it's not obvious which extension method is involved. The result here is that `_contains` gets initialized with the method info we need.

You've already got the property info for the target property, so let's put them together:

```
// The parameter for the predicate
var row = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "row");

// Constant for the filter value
var filter = Expression.Constant(filterValue);

// Get the value of the property
var prop = Expression.Property(property);

// Call 'Contains' on the property value
var body = Expression.Call(prop, _contains, filter);

// Finally, generate the lambda
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>(body, row);

// Apply to the query
query = query.Where(predicate);
```

Or in slightly more compact form:

```
var row = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "row");
var predicate = 
    Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>
    (
        Expression.Call
        (
            Expression.Property(row, property),
            _contains,
            Expression.Constant(filterValue)
        ),
        row
    );
```

When you're working on data via `IEnumerable<T>` instead, `predicate.Compile()` will produce a working `Func<T, bool>` to pass to `IEnumerable.Where()`:

```
private static readonly MethodInfo _tostring = typeof(Object).GetMethod("ToString");
static readonly MethodInfo _compare = (((Expression<Func<string, bool>>)(s => s.Contains(""))).Body as MethodCallExpression).Method;

public static IEnumerable<T> Search<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string propertyName, string filterValue)
{
    var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    var row = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "row");
    
    // Let's make sure we're actually dealing with a string here
    Expression prop = Expression.Property(row, property);
    if (property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
        prop = Expression.Call(prop, _tostring);
    
    var func = 
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
        (
            Expression.Call
            (
                prop,
                _compare,
                Expression.Constant(filterValue)
            ),
            row
        ).Dump().Compile();

    return items.Where(func);
}
```

Expressions are pretty versatile, and there are a lot of places where they come in handy. It can be more efficient to compose a function and call it multiple times than to go through reflection all the time, and you can do interesting things with merging expressions and so on.

Comment: That's perfect code and It's like a course to me. I like the Idea of using the Extension Method and I have 2 problems using it 1st the type of _tostring field is not mentioned and the code  shows errors I tried MethodInfo but it shows other errors. 2nd is it memory efficient to use Extension Method with IEnumerable<T> since we should get data first and then filter it based on the output, can't we just use the Extension for IQueryable<T> instead?

Comment: Error is: Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression' in this line: prop = Expression.Call(prop, _tostring); and it's not possible to cast explicitly

Comment: @AshkanKhalaj Yeah, I typed that in a hurry, sorry. `MethodCallExpression` and `MemberExpression` both derive from `Expression` so explicitly typing the variable works.